# Conflicting events in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code:

```
<div class="MediaPreview" style="left: 10px; bottom: 10px;">
   <span>Image or video, required</span>
   <div class="x">x</div>
</div>
```

Now I have a hover over effect which displays the X. What I'm looking for now is to attach an `onclick event` to the div with a class of `x` so that when they click it handles the action. **Currently it does this but when it finishes it performs the onclick event for the MediaPreview class subsequently**

Not quite sure what to do hear. I'm looking for help/answers. **A solution would be to isolate the onclick to the X text and then not have a subsequent event loaded**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `e.stopPropagation()` to stop the event from bubbling up to the parent.

If you show us your actual code, we can show you where to plug in `e.stopPropagation()` in your click handler.  Please remember that questions about code should always include the relevant code.